# How do I add a column of objects to a dataframe initialized by values from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table of stock symbols I'm pulling from a csv file:

```
      Symbol      Last      Open %Change     ATR Earnings Date                  Sector
153        WHR    138.02    139.21  -2.26%    4.50       01 / 25  Consumer Discretionary
154        WIX     76.86     80.05  -5.33%    4.01       02 / 07  Information Technology
155         WM    158.03    158.60  -0.78%    3.10       02 / 01             Industrials
156        WMT    143.09    144.77  -1.44%    2.58       02 / 07        Consumer Staples
157        YUM    127.71    128.50  -0.83%    2.17       02 / 07  Consumer Discretionary
```

And I want to construct data objects of class TaData for each symbol and add it to a new column.

TaData for a single symbol is normally constructed like this:

```
data = TaData('GOOG')
```

I want something like this (that didn't work since it passed in the whole column instead of individual symbols):

```
df = pd.read_csv('watchlist.csv')
df['ta_data'] = TaData(df['Symbol'])
```

Is a for loop my only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think pandas apply function would be useful for you. Find more about pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

You can try the following:-

```
df['ta_data'] = df['Symbol'].apply(lambda x: TaData(x))
```

Comment: That totally worked.  Thanks!!